# Replace operation is not working in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to replace the Marks field value for id 235 in my pandas data frame, df. Earlier it was 65 & I want to replace it to 75
So I wrote following code

```
df.at['235', 'Marks'] = 75
```

After that I'm trying to see if that replace is working or not.So I wrote

```
df.at['235', 'Marks']
```

and it's giving value as 75
But when I'm trying to see the columns against id by using following code

```
df[df['id']=='235'].head()
```

I'm seeing old value 65 in marks field. Can you please help me to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `id` the primary index of the dataframe? If you didn't do any additional modifications to the dataframe, using df.at['235', ...] would use the index first and not the column "id" that you reference later in the statement. The default index in pandas dataframes is the row number. `df.loc[df['id'] == '235', 'Marks'] =`  should be the statement you're looking for.

An example that the pattern you're using should work if the correct index is supplied:-

```
data = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'])
df.at[0, "Name"] = "lolname"
df.at[0, "Name"]
=> 'lolname'
df
=> 
      Name  Age
    0  lolname   10
    1      Bob   12
    2   Clarke   13
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `df.loc`

```
df.loc[df.ID == 235, 'Marks'] = 75
```

`df.at` basically works based on row_num if it is not indexed.